# Is there a way to export SVG files from Adobe XD without id's?

Tags: website-design, svg, html, adobe-xd

When exporting (for example) icons from Adobe XD as SVG files, the code contains ID's that are for me unnecessary. When I want to use the SVG files for instance inline in an HTML file, it will give ID duplications. I can get rid of the ID's manually, but I would like to know if there is a way to remove the ID's before exporting from XD?

E.g.:

```
<clipPath id="a"><clipPath id="c"><g id="b" clip-path="url(#c)"><g clip-path="url(#a)">
```

When you use more than one svg file, you will have duplications ID's :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="84" height="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84"><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="47.5"
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="84" height="84" viewBox="0 0 84 84"><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="47.203"
```

The export settings I use (tried also the other options, without result):

[image: export settings]

I could not find this topic on the Adobe XD forums.

Comment: I don't know about doing this from inside your Adobe software, but there are SVG optimizing tools like [Scour](https://github.com/scour-project/scour) that can automatically remove unused ids (```--enable-id-stripping```). Also, for ```<clipPath>```, IDs are *required*, otherwise you can't reference and use them on other elements.